# Matlab engine "run" with ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, matlab, matlab-engine

I have created a Ruby on Rails web application. This application created an Input-Data file at the end for a Problem which is formulated in Matlab. Now I want start the Matlab Problem with the help of a button in the web application. How can I start Matlab from Ruby on Rails? I tried the following without success:

```
    system "C\\Programme\\MATLAB\\R2016a\\bin\\matlab Main_Application.m"
```

Has anyone a solution for my problem?

Comment: You need to use "-r" option if you want to run specific code on MATLAB startup. See http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_env/startup-options.html

Comment: Also, you will want to think about non-blocking calls (e.g. spawning of processes); for a Rails app a gem like [sidekiq](http://sidekiq.org), and/or [Active Job](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_job_basics.html) would be useful.

Comment: It works! Thanks for help!